# isSplittable() method

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a question on isSplitable() of FileInputFormat class. As per the definition this method will restrict to create multiple mapper on the input split. But the number of mapper is based on the number of splits of a file. Like a 160 MB file is broken into 3 splits say 64, 64 and 32 MB. There will be 3 map tasks, one for each input split. If I override isSplitable() with the false value, what it will restrict, any way there will be 3 mappers to process the file based on the input splits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want your data file to split or you want a single mapper which will process your entire file. So that one file will be processed by only one mapper. In that case extending map/reduce inputformat and overriding isSplitable() method and return "false" as boolean  will help you.

Spliting and reading the entire file as a chunk are 2 different things.